# Draw JSON data to canvas using ajax and store JSON items in variables

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, canvas

Hi I have written this code to get JSON data from a text file and draw the shape on the canvas i managed to get the data from JSON to all be drawn on the canvas but now I want to store each shape as a variable so that i can refer to it later on in the code if a user clicks on it.

I have written this code to try this but it only draws one rectangle and it doesnt even draw the text inside it which should be shown inside of it.

Here is my Code...

```
function ajax_GetCanvasData(){
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var context = document.getElementById("drawing_canvas").getContext('2d');

    req.open("GET", "List.php", true);
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(req.responseText);

            for(var item in data){
                if (data[item].type == "Node"){

                    var text = data[item].text;
                    var cx = data[item].cx;
                    var cy = data[item].cy;
                    var width = data[item].width;
                    var height = data[item].height;
                    var colour = data[item].colour;

                    node = new nodeObj(context,text,cx,cy,width,height,colour);
                }

            }
        }
    }
    req.send(null);
}

function nodeObj(context,text,cx,cy,width,height,colour) {

    this.text = text;
    this.cx = cx;
    this.cy = cy;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.colour = colour;

    var lineheight = 15

    context.fillStyle = colour;
    context.fillRect(cx,cy,width,height);
    context.strokeRect(cx,cy,width,height);

    context.fillStyle = '#000000';
    context.font = 'bold 12px Ariel, sans-serif';
    context.textAlign = 'center';
    context.textBaseline = 'ideographic';
    wrapText(context, text, cx + (width*0.5), cy+(height*0.5), width, lineHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using a library like [paper.js](http://paperjs.org/).
It allows you to retain object references to what was drawn on canvas in the form of paths. These you can manipulate programmatically afterwards.

It seems like exactly what you want to do.

Here's a screencast I've created on using paperjs: http://tagtree.tv/canvas-with-paper-js, it's a perfect primer for what you would like to do.